# Facebook Instant Articles Track Errors

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

there is any way to track errors in Facebook Instant Articles? I want check which published posts gave errors for any particular reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Been through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/guides/support-overview already?

Comment: Not the best approach, but you can go to the Instant Articles under your page settings and open the article in the online Editor, if there are any issues with the article markup, they should show up there. However, this does not work if you are talking about article that were not ingested from the feed. If it is the latter, then you should compare your feed with the example in the docs and ensure that the structure is correct and you are not missing out on any tags.